# PL/SQL: How To Loop Through The Same File Twice Using UTL_FILE.GET_LINE?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am working on a project where I am processing a large read-only text file that comes in with a header and a footer.  The header and footer need to be stripped before processing the file.  Removing the header was easy, but to remove the footer I need a total line count.  In order to get the line count I created a function that loops through the entire file using UTL_FILE.GET_LINE, and increments a counter for each line.  This works and gives me the proper line count.  When it comes time to actually process the file now that we have a line count the pointer is now pointing at the end of file, so I immediately come out of the loop and do not process the file at all.

So my question is how can I reset the pointer so the second time I loop through the file we are starting at the beginning?  If there is a better way to get the total line count of the text file, I'd be open to those suggestions as well.  My original plan was to use UTL_FILE.FSEEK to reset the pointer, but since the file is read-only that will not work.  Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Are you prevented from using external tables or SQL*Loader?

Comment: Do you really need to remove the footer before you start processing? Can't you just handle it when you get to the last line of the file?

Comment: I think it would be preferred that no external tables be used.  Multiples of these large files are processed daily.  Not entirely sure how external tables work (PL/SQL is not really my area of expertise), but I wouldn't want to create a bunch of garbage tables every day.   Not removing the footer causes bad data to be entered into the database when the footer is reached.  Depending on the source of the file the footer will have a different format, so it was difficult to determine proper data from the footer without a row count.

Comment: UTL_FILE.FSEEK was my first plan, but it my understanding that it only works with a read/write file and my file is read-only.

Comment: external tables are simply a table-view over the top of a file. You set up a table that points to the file and describes the contents of the file. If the file changes but the filename and data structure remain the same, the external table will simply show the new file contents without you having to do anything. The benefit of external tables is that you can then query it using SQL. I.e. to insert the contents into a different table, it's just `insert into some_table (...) select .... from your_external_table`. You can amend/filter the data you load by amending the select stmt as appropriate

Comment: However, if you can't use external tables, I second APC's comment of just handling the last line when you discover it's the last line, but that would probably mean changing your code to store the information somewhere first (e.g. an array, a global temporary table (aka GTT), a normal (heap) table, etc) before going and doing the processing afterwards (I'm guessing you pick up the 2nd line, process it, pick up the 3rd line, process it, etc?).

Comment: An external table would let you put all your incoming records into a work table as a VARCHAR2 of appropriate length to handle the largest record.  Then let your process detect and process the different record formats from the work table.  Another plus to external tables is that you can alter them to reference different files if your files arrive with different names but the same format.

Answer (score 0):

How about, defer processing until you have read the next line? If the next line is present, you know this one is a data row. If not, it's a footer.

Alternatively, just cache everything in a temp table with a sequence # as a key and then kill the MIN and the MAX.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your help.  I got permission to change the file to read/write and was just able to use UTL_FILE.FSEEK.